# Writing solely pixel data to a GTK_IMAGE

Tags: c++, gtk, gtk3, gdk

I have raw pixel data with simple boolean color (on = 1, off = 0).  Essentially, a black and white image written in hex.  I am trying to place this data on a GTK_IMAGE in my GUI using the following code (NOTE, c++):

```
GtkWidget *image
GdkPixbufLoader *loader;
const unsigned char hexData[] = {0x80, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, etc}; //This will put evenly spaced pixels
gdk_pixbuf_loader_write(loader, hexData, strlen((char *)hexData), NULL); 
gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(image), gdk_pixbuf_loader_get_pixbuf(loader));
```

The application will compile and start correctly, but when accessing the method that contains this algorithm, I get the errors:

```
gdk_pixbuf_loader_write: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF_LOADER (loader)' failed
gdk_pixbuf_loader_get_pixbuf: assertion 'GDK_IS_PIXBUF_LOADER (loader)' failed
```

Anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: FYI: [GdkPixbuf - Image Data](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk-pixbuf/class.Pixbuf.html#image-data)

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work, is because you haven't initialized your `GdkPixbufLoader` yet. In other words, you probably want to use something like [`gdk_pixbuf_loader_new()`](https://docs.gtk.org/gdk-pixbuf/ctor.PixbufLoader.new.html) first. Note that you should also use `g_object_unref()` when you're done with it (to make sure its resources are deallocated).

To get more information about the `GdkPixbufLoader` class and how to use it, you might want to visit https://docs.gtk.org/gdk-pixbuf/class.PixbufLoader.html

Comment: Well, the error is gone (thanks!), though now there is just...no image.